# I have a USBC to usb cable, can I use the usbc port in my computer and then attach the usb part to a monitor?

Tags: display, external-display, dell-inspiron

I am to receive a Dell monitor soon. I have one cable with a UBSC and USB one each end. My computer has a usbc port, while the dell monitor only has hdmi,vga, and regular usb ports.
Will my monitor work with my laptop if I plug in the usbc cable into my computer and put the usb part of the cable into the monitor?
Thanks!

Dell monitor is: Dell P2219H (22", 1920 x 1080 pixels), ends of cable has USB A and USB C

Comment: Which exact model is your Dell monitor?

Comment: Does the other end have USB type A or B?

Comment: Dell monitor is: Dell P2219H (22", 1920 x 1080 pixels), and other end has USB type A

Comment: [per specs](https://www.dell.com/en-ie/shop/dell-22-monitor-p2219h/apd/210-apwr/monitors-monitor-accessories#techspecs_section) it has: USB 3.0 upstream (Type B), 
2 x USB 3.0 downstream (Type A), 
2 x USB 2.0 downstream (Type A) - ports -> so if you want to use the A ports on the monitor you need to bring the USB connections from your laptop to the B ports as the monitor has a USB Hub so you will need a USB C to B cable to be able to use the A ports on the monitor

Comment: “put the usb part of the cable into the monitor?” - No; Your monitor must specifically support this and it doesn’t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. USB ports on the monitor work as a USB hub only. You're supposed to connect the monitor to the laptop with a USB type A → USB type B cable. Other USB ports on the monitor will work like extensions of the laptop's USB port.

Comment: +1, In addition: Even though USB-C is usually the input, not output, USB-A is always the output.

Comment: I see. Thank you!!! I will just purchase an hdmi cable then as I have two ports for them. That would be the best option right?

Comment: @wabash Go either for HDMI or DisplayPort (if your graphics card outputs DP signal). DP is more advanced, but for this monitor there's no difference.

Comment: @LPChip With the exception of some Chinese no-name external drive enclosures, which come with a non-standard A→A cable and a type A socket. And this rule doesn't hold for smaller USB form factors. And there's also the A/B variant. USB is a mess :)

Comment: @gronostaj right... there are always exceptions to the rule. These exceptions are usually a case of... Eh, I need to connect this, I have this cable, lets use this... kind of approach.